# Django many-to-many making too many calls

Tags: django, django-orm

I have a simple m2m relationship as below:

```
class Category(ModelBase):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    icon = models.CharField(max_length=50)


class Course(ModelBase):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)       
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category, related_name="courses")
```

I am using ListView to show all the courses in a category or all courses if no category provided.

views.py

```
class CourseListView(ListView):


   model = Course
    paginate_by = 15
    template_name = "courses.html"
    context_object_name = "courses"

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = (
            super()
            .get_queryset()
            .select_related("tutor")
            .prefetch_related("categories")
            .filter(active=True)
        )
        category_id = self.kwargs.get("category_id")
        return (
            queryset
            if not category_id
            else queryset.filter(categories__in=[category_id])
        )

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs: Any) -> Dict[str, Any]:
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        category_id = self.kwargs.get("category_id")
        if category_id:
            context["current_category"] = Category.objects.get(id=category_id)
        context["categories"] = Category.objects.all()
        return context
```

Django is making duplicate calls as I am doing something like this in the template.

```
<div class="icon"><span class="{{ course.categories.first.icon }}"></span></div>
```

Not sure why, help much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You can also use `{{ course.categories.all.0.icon }}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `.prefetch_related('categories')` the result of this prefetch will be used when you access `course.categories.all`. Any other queryset on `course.categories` will do a fresh query. Since `course.categories.first` is a new queryset, it does not use the prefetched result.

What you want to access in your template is the first result from `course.categories.all()`. But this is not easy in the template. I would recommend a method on the `Course` model:

```
class Course(...):
    ...

    def first_category(self):
        # Equivalent to self.categories.first(), but uses the prefetched categories
        categories = self.categories.all()
        if len(categories):
            return categories[0]
        else:
            return None
```

And then in your template you can call this method

```
<div class="icon"><span class="{{ course.first_category.icon }}"></span></div>
```

Comment: Why did you use here `len(categories)` and not `if categories.exists()` for example ? Source : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/optimization/#use-queryset-exists

Comment: categories.exists() is a new query and won't use the prefetched result. len(categories) checks the length of the data already retrieved in the prefetch and requires no additional queries. The point here is to not make any additional queries.

Comment: It is more efficient to use `try except` block instead of `len()`, which loads all objects in memory.

Comment: I think all objects are already loaded in memory due to the prefetch. That's the point of this question.

Answer (score 1):

You can also access the first value like:

```
{{ course.categories.all.0.icon }}
```

It is not necessary to write a method.

Answer (score 0):

because categories is `ManyToMany` which means one category may appear in many courses, but in the template you just calling the first category's icon, so there maybe more than two course with the same first category, and it will retrieve them all, i recommend using another for loop to loops through categories too.

```
{% for course in courses %}
<div>
    <h1>{{ course.name</h1>
    ......
    <h4>categories</h4>
    {% for category in course.categories %}
         <div class="icon"><span class="{{ category.icon }}"></span></div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks, you are correct. But I don't want to iterate as that will add icon multiple times?